# How to set environment variables in CoreOS

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I need to set environment variable in kubernetes slave which is a coreos system.
I have tried using `export`and `declare` but it keeps reading each argument as a separate command

Comment: can you show what you tried?

Comment: I had tried `export VAR=34` and similarly `declare`

Comment: Are you doing this from the command line or in something like a systemd unit file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't set variables in the `command` field, take a look at the `env` field.

Answer (score 1):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: api
  name: api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: api
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: VARIABLE       <---- declare an env variable NAME
          value: "value-of-variable"   <--- here is the value
        - name: ANOTHER_VARIABLE
          value: "another-value"
        image: myregistry/api
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: api
```

Comment: Thanks, but of which file do you show the contents?

Comment: this is the ReplicationController file (YAML) for the example Pod named 'api' here.
This sets the env variable for the container in the pod.